# Why isn't this Selenium opening the website I'm requesting?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")
options.add_argument(r"--profile-directory=Profile 11")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com')
time.sleep(25)
driver.quit()
```

I'm attempting to write a script that opens google, picks a Chrome profile, and goes to a website. The code above opens google and signs into the profile but it does not go to Facebook. Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Any errors thrown?

Comment: Did you try using navigate instead of get? I've never used it with a profile so I'm not sure if that matters.